# Extend Mongoose model without storing all properties

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a CMS based on Node.js+Express+Mongoose. I want abstract layers for business and data access methods. So I have biz classes containing the methods with the calls to the database.

These calls are made using directly the Mongoose models, so **my logical entities are Mongoose entities**.

The problem is that **some logical entity is not always identical to its database entity**.

For example: I have a model called "Item" with its properties and these properties have to be stored into the database, that's just fine. Now, I need a new property, an array called "similar_items" that can, eventually, contain a list of other items but I don't want to store this property inside the database.

```
var itemSchema = new Schema({
    id: { type: Number, index: true },
    name: { type: String }
});

var item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);    
var data = new Item();
/* do stuff....  */
data.similar_items = blahblah; //I can't set this property as it doesn't exists!
```

Is it possible to extend a Mongoose model with properties out of its schema? I know I can define virtual properties with getters and setters, but I still don't have a "place" to store my array.

Any idea? **Should I separate my logical and Mongoose models?**

Comment: Can you expand a bit on what happens to `data` after you add `similar_items` to it?  Do you save it or does it go off to another layer?

Comment: it simply doesn't set the variable. If I do this data.similar_items = [1,2,3] and then I inspect the object with console.log(data) it doesn't show the similar_items property. I guess Mongoose hooks the property, it check if it's in schema and if not it removes it.

Comment: Right, what I was getting at is that if you're done using `data` as a Mongoose instance at that point, call `data = data.toObject();` to convert it to a plain JS object that you can add properties to.

Comment: ah! well I haven't tried. Let me see.

Comment: Ehi, it works! Post the answer so I can flag it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're done using `data` as a Mongoose instance at that point, call [`toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) on it to convert it to a plain JS object that you can freely modify:

```
data = data.toObject();
data.similar_items = blahblah;
```

Comment: Another option is to create a property in the schema and set the property to default to `null`, anticipating it will be set dynamically later.  You could set it in a `.post('init')` middleware after a `.find()` if the empty property is already set.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add extra property with mongoose model without specifying it in schema. if you want to save the added property you have to add this in schema level. otherwise use `toobject()` method to transfer it in normal javascript object.

```
data = data.toObject();
data.any_property_name = required_value;
```

one thing you can not save this object in database. As it is a plain javascript object.